# Limit group by access query with a date range

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having trouble with an Access SQL query (I'm familiar with MS SQL).  I'm getting an error trying to limit my query to dates within the past year. The DataTable is organized with a sales amount for each city-date.

```
    SELECT A.City, A.Region, Sum(A.Sales) AS TotalRev
    FROM DataTable AS A
    WHERE A.Date<=DateAdd("dd",-365,Date())
    GROUP BY A.Month, A.City, A.Region
```

The error I'm receiving is "invalid procedural call"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the reason is that `dd` is not a valid interval in MS Access (here is the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateAdd-Function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19)).  Try this:

```
SELECT A.City, A.Region, Sum(A.Sales) AS TotalRev
FROM DataTable AS A
WHERE A.Date <= DateAdd("d", -365, Date())
GROUP BY A.Month, A.City, A.Region;
```

That said, I don't see why you have `A.Month` in the `GROUP BY`, but not the `SELECT`.  In addition, this query does the opposite of what you want.  I would expect something more like:

```
SELECT A.City, A.Region, Sum(A.Sales) AS TotalRev
FROM DataTable AS A
WHERE A.Date >= DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Date())
GROUP BY A.City, A.Region;
```

Comment: Whoops; was trying to simplify my query and left the month in the group by by mistake--the "d" instead of "dd" solved it